# How can I get the value of a child node from the conditions of its sibling

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use the value of the `name` node to get back the `location` or other sibling nodes in the code below

```
var xmlString ="<stock><item><name> jacket </name><price> 10 </price><location> lat: 31.956624, lng: 35.860534</location></item><item><name> shirt </name><price> 5 </price><location> lat: 31.938761, lng: 35.887909</location></item><item><name> shoes</name><price> 40</price><location> lat: 31.981340,lng: 35.839020</location></item></stock>"
        var myParser = new DOMParser();

        var xmlObject = myParser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml") 

        var xmlResults = document.evaluate("/stock/item/name[contains(text(), 'jacket')]", xmlObject, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

        var singleResult = xmlResults.iterateNext();

        while (singleResult){
            console.log(singleResult.textContent);
            singleResult = xmlResults.iterateNext();
        }
```

The above text will just return `jacket`.
What I need is to use `jacket` or other `name` value to return the values of siblings of `name`
e.g. input jacket into search form and get coordinates to use it to place a pin on a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/stock/item[contains(name, "jacket")]/location/text()`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but is there a way that xPath can take the `jacket` value from an html input, say a search bar maybe?